# Removing Windows 8 to run Ubuntu OS on an Intel i7 7348

Tags: intel

How do I remove Windows 8 & load only Ubuntu as my OS on an Intel i7 7348

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a bootable Linux USB stick on Windows OS.(You can see steps of it [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0))
2. Then, boot computer from USB after booting it, there will be two option install ubuntu and try ubuntu. Choose install ubuntu and next steps until you come partition part when you came there select choose something else option then format windows partition to EXT4 and assign mount point to '/'.
3. After these steps linux will be installed and restarted. You can search creating swap area while partition from net.

Comment: You should probably add OP has to alter the boot order to get the system to boot from USB!

Comment: And supposedly Ubuntu is already installed in dual boot, or not?